# Spring RssChannelHttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Does anyone have an example of using the Spring RssChannelHttpMessageConverter to generate a rss podcast?

This is what I have so far.

```
@Controller
public class FeedController {

private Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Mashaller;

@Autowired
public void setJaxb2Mashaller(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Mashaller) {
    this.jaxb2Mashaller = jaxb2Mashaller;
}

@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET, value="/emps",
        headers="Accept=application/rss+xml")
public @ResponseBody SyndFeed getFeed(){

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Show");
    List<Show> l = query.list();

    SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedImpl();
    feed.setFeedType("rss2.0");

    feed.setTitle("some podcast");
    feed.setLink("you");
    feed.setDescription("description");
    feed.setCopyright("c_me");

    List<SyndEntry> entries = new ArrayList<SyndEntry>();

    for(Show e : l) {

        SyndEntry entry = new SyndEntryImpl();
        entry.setTitle(e.getTitle());
        entries.add(entry);

    }


    feed.setEntries(entries);
    System.out.println(feed);
    return feed;
}

}
```

When calling the controller I get a 406 Not Acceptable

Here is some snippets of my spring config

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingConverter" />
            <ref bean="atomConverter"  />
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="marshallingConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="atomConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.feed.RssChannelHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/rss+xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>

<!-- Client -->
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingConverter" />
            <ref bean="atomConverter"  />
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jaxbMarshaller"
      class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>

            <value>com.Show</value>
        </list>
    </property>


</bean>
```

Comment: How are you calling your controller ? Which client ? A RSS reader ?

Comment: Make sure, than when you call the controller, the HttpRequest have `Accept=application/rss+xml` in header